# Why is PyGame not spawning a new letter?

Tags: python, pygame

I have come up with some game idea and so I have this code below. But when I use the if statement, something like `print('Nice work')` would print something. But when I use the function `message()` I made, it won't work! Here is my code(I have put a `# Here is where it doesn't work` to help you find this bit):

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *

# Set the height and width of the screen
window_width = 700
window_height = 500
size = [window_width, window_height]
game_win = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Creating colors
white = (225, 225, 225)
black = (0, 0, 0)
gray = (100, 100, 100)

# Setting a font
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("consolas", 25)
large_font = pygame.font.SysFont("consolas", 80)

# Setting a window name
pygame.display.set_caption("Letters Game")


# Creating a messaging function
def message(sentence, color, x, y, font_type, display):
    sentence = font_type.render(sentence, True, color)
    display.blit(sentence, [x, y])


# Main function
def mainLoop():
    # Creating a letter list
    letters = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    random_letter = random.choice(letters)

    # Initializing PyGame
    pygame.init()

    # variable to keep a loop going
    done = False

    y = 20
    y_moved = 0

    random_x = random.choice(list(range(50, 550)))

    # Starting a loop
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            y_moved = 7
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.unicode == random_letter.lower():
                    message(random_letter, white, random_x, y, large_font, game_win)
                    pygame.display.flip()

        y += y_moved
        game_win.fill(black)

        message("Type the letter before it touches the line", white, 10, 10, font, game_win)

        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [0, 450, 700, 5])

        message(random_letter, white, random_x, y, large_font, game_win)
        # Here is where it doesn't work
        if y >= 700 - y:
            message(random_letter, white, random_x, y, large_font, game_win)
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.event.poll()

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        clock.tick(25)
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainLoop()
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you subtracting `y` in `if y >= 700 - y:`? Also, call `pygame.display.flip()` **only once** each game loop; don't call it in your event loop and in your if statement. Why are you calling `pygame.event.poll()` in your if statement? All it does is to clear a random event from the queue, which is unnecessary (and potentially missing important events!) since you got an event loop handling all events already. Don't create a new clock every loop (with `clock = pygame.time.Clock()`). Because of it, `clock.tick(25)` has no effect. Create it before the loop.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I am subtracting so that the program notices it when the letter's bottom touches the line and not when the top of the letter touches the line.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't you subtract its height and not its position?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Oh ok thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the letter touches the line, you can simply generate new x-position, set y-position to 0 and generate a new random letter.

You can replace:

```
if y >= 700 - y:
    message(random_letter, white, random_x, y, large_font, game_win         
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.poll()
```

With this:

```
if y >= 700 - y:
    message(random_letter, white, random_x, y, large_font, game_win)
    random_letter = random.choice(letters)
    y = 0
    random_x = random.choice(list(range(50, 550)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if event.unicode == random_letter.lower():
    message(random_letter, white, random_x, y, large_font, game_win)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Can't work because display.blit need to be called every time or it just display once. Also, one pygame.display.flip() at the bottom is enough.

Simple solution:
return the object that you want to display, save it into a list and every time loop through the list and call display.blit()

Should work fine

Hope I could help
Greets